# As a MS Gold Partner can I install Visual Studio 2010 Pro instead of Premium?

Tags: visual-studio, licensing, msdn

As [Microsoft Gold Partners we are granted 10 versions of Visual Studio Premium](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2010/04/msdn-partner-benefits-for-visual-studio.html). We have 13 developers so 10 of use use Premium and 3 of use use VS Professional. Is it allowed to install 10 copies of VS Professional instead of Premium to keep everyone consistent?

Comment: I think you should ask Microsoft. They are the only one who can give a relevant answer.

Comment: Hard to see why they would object against you installing the lesser version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, thanks for referring to my post.

After reading around and talking to my MS representative, my understanding is that you can safely use Professional instead of Premium under the license.

On MSDN you can always download your highest available version and the versions below. And since the serial# is embedded it's all a matter of playing nice towards the licensing rules.

That said, I would let 10 people have Premium since it includes more nice tools like performance profiling and code metrics. It shouldn't interfere with the other 3.